# Is it possible to run column chromatography in reversed phase?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, chromatography

I'm conducting a synthesis involving aza-crown-ether.
Whether aza-crown-ether acts as a base or not is unclear, but when I do TLC using dichloromethane/methanol, it is hardly drawn up with the mobile phase (see image below).

[image: TLC result of aza-crown-ether in toluene]

I assume it is very polar (or basic), and I have to run reversed phase chromatography.
Whenever I search for reversed phase chromatography, all texts consider reversed-phase 'HPLC'.
Is column chromatography in reversed phase impossible? I have never found sources about it.

I used a dichloromethane/methanol ratio of 3:1. Do I have to keep the ratio of methanol to not exceed 10%? Should I use reversed-phase TLC or try using dichloromathane/methanol in 10% ammonia and add some triethylamine?

Comment: AFAIK there are/were RP (HP)TLC alu sheets or glass plates, or free SF as well, but you could have the different problem being washed away.// You may need more polar MF as you mention. Or some conditioning of SF, e.g. in a chamber with  aquaous ammonia.

Comment: That TLC makes it seem DCM:MeOH is still doable with normal phase chromatography. Reverse phase is much more expensive, the silica costs 10-100x as much. It's not uncommon to go as far as adding a few percent water or aqueous ammonia to the eluent if necessary, for extremely polar compounds.

Comment: I second the suggestion of adding ammonia to your eluent. I have routinely used DCM/MeOH/NH3 systems for columning basic materials. Ammonia is MeOH is commercially available which is what I used. You could also consider chromatography on alumina.

Comment: What are eluents used for structures similar to the one you target?  What stationary phase is reported there?  Note, alumina Waylander suggested is available as acidic/neuter/basic. Is TLC intended as to monitor the progress of the reaction (because of what looks like a pale spot at Rf ~ 0.8, perhaps easier to see if the lane were stained with $\ce{KMnO4}$)?  If aiming for purification, could protonation and subsequent extraction represent an alternative (e.g., cyclam) to chromatography?

Comment: @Buttonwood TLC image I uploaded was visualized by ninhydrin. In other papers using aza-crown-ether, they use ethyl acetate or hexane/ethyl acetate (5:1 to 1:1). One strange thing is when I use these solvent systems, TLC results were still challenging.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks for comment, but what does 'SF' and 'MF' stand for?

Comment: Ah, I see reason for confusion, I applied abbreviating of Czech words, not English ones :-D  - so it would be  SP and MP, or SPh and MPh, ( stationary/mobile phase), not quite sure which is common now.

Comment: You may have to consider whether you are looking at a metallated or non-metallated aza-crown. If there's a metal ion inside it, the affinity for the silica will increase enormously.

Comment: @KrangLee If possible, run a TLC with multiple lanes: starting material(s), (quenched) reaction mixture, *co-spot* starting material and quenched reaction mixture. Maybe the *differences* in the Rf values are already *good enough* (the pale perhaps-spot around 0.8?) and  a short column already provides sufficient separation / purification.  Or, that you elute with a gradient.  This assumes you stick to chromatography as purification, as (back) extraction / recrystallization may be alternatives.