# Problem about TLC solvent and staining

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I am conducting an organic synthesis involving 1-aza-18-crown-6-ether. I tried TLC, but they didn't work well. I have tried: (1) hexane+ethyl acetate in various ratio, (2) dichloromethane:methanol=3:1, (3) chloroform:methanol:ammonium hydroxide solution(28~30%)=5:3:1

In case of (2), as previously I asked here, aza-crown hardly drew up. ( [Is it possible to run column chromatography in reversed phase?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/154174/is-it-possible-to-run-column-chromatography-in-reversed-phase) )
(additional question : Is it possible to show two spot in TLC by one material? TLC image I uploaded seems to have two spots, but it has only one material, 1-aza-18-crown-6-ether. Solvent is toluene, which evaporates fast.)

In case of (3), because aza-crown spot can't be observed by UV, I use ninhydrin as staining solution. I saw the paper which uses solvent system (3) (actually it used ammonia), but because of ammonium hydroxide, TLC plate turns all red after staining. Many people recommended adding ammonia in the previous question, but ninhydrin may stain it also. Should I change staining solution?

Comment: Throughly dry the tlc plate with a hot air blower before staining with ninhydrin. Also try a permanganate spray + heating for visualising it. Could also try adding triethylamine instead of ammonia.

Comment: @Waylander Thank you for comment. May I ask additional question? There are two methods of staining, dipping and spraying. What method would you recommend?

Comment: Whichever is easiest for you. I used to keep a pot of aq KMnO4 solution at the back of the fumehood for dipping plates. You can sometimes see the spots as soon as the solution is running off the plate.

Comment: @Waylander Actually I was worried about contaminating staining solution by multiple dipping. Does this problem have few effect?

Comment: Not really a problem, there's only a tiny amount of organic material in a TLC sample.

Comment: @Waylander Thanks a lot! I would try the methods you answered.

Comment: This may be useful http://www.cchem.berkeley.edu/rsgrp/TLCStainRecipes.pdf